# postgres combining two queries from the result between them

Tags: postgresql

I Have two postgres query.
This is the first query

```
SELECT line.quantity, inv.origin, spo.lot_id 
FROM account_invoice inv 
INNER JOIN account_invoice_line line on inv.id=line.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN stock_picking pick on inv.origin=pick.name 
LEFT JOIN stock_pack_operation spo ON pick.id=spo.picking_id 
WHERE line.product_id=4988 
AND pick.min_date between '2021-02-20' and '2021-03-22';
```

with result

```
quantity |    origin     | lot_id 
----------+---------------+--------
25.00 | SNL/OUT/02317 |   6528
25.00 | SNL/OUT/02306 |   6774
150.00 | SNL/OUT/02337 |   6774
```

And the second query is

```
SELECT spo.product_qty, spo.lot_id 
FROM stock_pack_operation spo 
LEFT JOIN stock_picking sp ON sp.id=spo.picking_id 
WHERE sp.origin='PO/2021/1/2307';
```

with the result of second query:

```
product_qty | lot_id 
-------------+--------
  200.00 |   6774
  200.00 |   6852
```

The question is what is the query to have result like this

```
quantity |    origin     | lot_id 
----------+---------------+--------
25.00 | SNL/OUT/02306 |   6774
150.00 | SNL/OUT/02337 |   6774
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: I'm not sure how the third result is a combination of the first two queries. Looks like it only depends on first query.

Comment: To combine queries, [CTE's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) can be very useful.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from query of tables?

Comment: First query is resulting in 3 rows which you want to further filter with criteria from the second query which is resulting in the 3 rows reducing to 2  rows. Is that so? If that is the case , the first query can be re-written to combine the criteria from the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. It use IN

```
SELECT line.quantity, inv.origin, spo.lot_id 
FROM account_invoice inv 
INNER JOIN account_invoice_line line on inv.id=line.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN stock_picking pick on inv.origin=pick.name 
LEFT JOIN stock_pack_operation spo ON pick.id=spo.picking_id 
WHERE line.product_id=4988 
AND pick.min_date between '2021-02-20' and '2021-03-22'
AND spo.lot_id IN
(SELECT spo2.lot_id 
FROM stock_pack_operation spo2 
LEFT JOIN stock_picking sp2 ON sp2.id=spo2.picking_id 
WHERE sp2.origin='PO/2021/1/2307');
```